# How to create dynamic Multiple And linq conditions in foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

```
    if (rowCount == 1)
    {
       query =
               (from x in partJoinTableRepository.GetPartJoinQuery()
                 join y in partRepository.GetPartsQuery() on x.PartId equals y.Id
                               join z in partProductTypeReposiotry.GetPartProductTypesQuery() on x.PartId equals z.PartId
                               where y.IsSkipped == 0 && (y.IsDisabled != "Y" || y.IsDisabled == null) && z.CreatedDate == x.CreatedDate
                               && x.CreatedDate == Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate) && cpaclassids.Contains(x.ProductTypeId.ToString())
                               select x).Cast<PartJoinTable>().AsQueryable();
                      predicate = PredicateBuilder.True(query);
   }
   else
   {   
    query = query.Join(partJoinTableRepository.GetPartJoinQuery(), "PartID", "PartID", "inner", "row1", null).Cast<PartJoinTable>().AsQueryable();
                        // predicate = PredicateBuilder.True(query);
   } //query contains multiple dynamic inner joins
       //repids contains the list ,I used the predicate builder for the linq to create AND Queries
   foreach(var item in repids)
   { 
      predicate = PredicateBuilder.True(query);
      if (typeid == "3")
      {
       predicate = predicate.And(z => ids.Contains(z.ProductTypeId.ToString()) && 
               z.CreatedDate == Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate));                            
      }
  }
var count = query.Where(predicate).Distinct().Count();
```

the above line is taking long time to execute,ids contains the lists and query contains the linq query.basically I need to form a multiple "AND" conditions

//The Query is taking lot of time to execute and multiple and conditions are not working

Comment: Multiple And Conditions are not formed..

Comment: if you want us to spend 5 minutes helping you, Spend 2 minutes tidying up your code. its a mess

Comment: foreach(var item in repids){ 
predicate = PredicateBuilder.True(query);
if (typeid == "3")
 {
     predicate = predicate.And(z => ids.Contains(z.ProductTypeId.ToString()) && 
     z.CreatedDate == Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate));                            
}
}
var count = query.Where(predicate).Distinct().ToList().Count();

Comment: There is an edit button

Comment: @TheGeneral,I have edited

Comment: What's the LINQ type? LINQ to Objects? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to XML?

Comment: linq to entities

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, your problem is that this query has a long running time. Let's see your code in the last line:

```
var count = query.Where(predicate).Distinct().ToList().Count();
```

In LINQ to SQL (and to entities), your query doesn't execute thought you use `ToList()`, `ToArray()` etc.. For example, consider the following query:

```
var strings = Db.Table
    .Where((string s) => s.Contains("A")) // Will convert to something like WHERE s LIKE '%A%'
    .Select(s => s.ToUpper()) // Will convert to something like SELECT upper(s)
    .ToList(); // Here the query sends to the DB and executes
```

The final query is `SELECT upper(s) FROM [Table] WHERE s LIKE '%A%'`.

In you case, first you send the query to the DB and get *all the objects corresponding to the condition (`.Where()`)*, and *then* get their count *inside your app*.

Instead, if you'll get from the DB only the count, the query will be faster:

```
var count = query.Where(predicate).Distinct().Count(); // No .ToList()! Here, .Count() executes the query.
```

Comment: removed ToList() and edited the code but still it is not working

Comment: @priyankha What's the problem? Again performance issues? Another problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ToList` to improve performance. Because `ToList` execute your query and retrieve object list to memory. But you need only count. you don't need objects.

```
var count = query.Where(predicate).Distinct().Count();
```